# Pick up relevant information from a string using regular expression C#3.0

Tags: c#-3.0

I have been given some file name which can be like

```
<filename>YYYYMMDD<fileextension>
```

some valid file names that will satisfy the above pattern are as under

```
xxx20100326.xls, 
xxx2v20100326.csv, 
x_20100326.xls,
xy2z_abc_20100326_xyz.csv,
abc.xyz.20100326.doc,
ab2.v.20100326.doc,
abc.v.20100326_xyz.xls
```

In what ever be the above defined case, I need to pick up the dates only. So for all the cases, the output will be **20100326**.

I am trying to achieve the same but no luck.

Here is what I have done so far

```
string testdata = "x2v20100326.csv";

string strYYYY = @"\d{4}";
string strMM = @"(1[0-2]|0[1-9])";
string strDD = @"(3[0-1]|[1-2][0-9]|0[1-9])";           
string regExPattern = @"\A" +  strYYYY + strMM + strDD +  @"\Z";
Regex regex = new Regex(regExPattern);
Match match = regex.Match(testdata);
if (match.Success)
{
  string result = match.Groups[0].Value;
}
```

I am using c#3.0 and dotnet framework 3.5

Please help. It is very urgent

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Characters \A and \Z - begin and end of the string respectivly.
I think you need pattern like:

```
string regExPattern = @"\A.*(?<FullDate>" +  strYYYY + strMM + strDD +  @").*\..*\Z";
```

".*" - any symbols at the begin
".*\..*" - any symbols before the dot, dot and any symbols after dot

And get a full date:

```
match.Groups["FullDate"]
```

Answer (score 1):

This one fetches the last date in the string.

```
        var re = new Regex("(?<date>[0-9]{8})");
        var test = "asdf_wef_20100615_sdf.csv";
        var datevalue = re.Match(test).Groups["date"].Value;
        Console.WriteLine(datevalue); // prints 20100615
```

Comment: Simple and right. Just name group in the Regex: "(?<date>[0-9]{8})"

Comment: SO "removes" <date> even if I've set the code in a <pre> tag. When I press edit I see it. How can I fix this?

Comment: As chapluck mention, the regex is "(?<date>[0-9]{8})"

Comment: Hmm.. Didn't work. Without the <pre> tag it works. Or is just the preview broken?

Comment: Found out I didn't need the <pre><code> tags as it does this automatically when indenting blocks of text

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
        DateTime result = DateTime.MinValue;
        System.Globalization.CultureInfo provider = System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture;

        var testString = "x2v20100326.csv";
        var format = "yyyyMMdd";
        try
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < testString.Length - format.Length; i++)
            {
                if (DateTime.TryParseExact(testString.Substring(i, format.Length), format, provider, System.Globalization.DateTimeStyles.None, out result))
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("{0} converts to {1}.", testString, result.ToString());
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
        catch (FormatException)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("{0} is not in the correct format.", testString);
        }
```

Comment: + to you because you get one good point: substring validation

Answer (score 0):

You may need to group things in your month and day expressions:

```
((1[0-2])|(0[1-9))
((3[0-1])|([1-2][0-9])|(0[1-9]))
```